# How to distinguish inputs from multiple joysticks on joy topic?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, joy-node, joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm currently working on a project that requires the use of multiple xbox 360 controllers to control a single robot (multi-master single-slave system). I can currently create two **joy_nodes**  that receive inputs from the separate controllers distinguishing themselves from each other by changing their names to **js0** and **js1**.

The issue is that both nodes publish to the **joy** topic so when subscribing to the topic (or using rostopic echo) it receives the inputs from both joysticks simultaneously. The question being how do I distinguish/separate the two joysticks from each other in the **joy** topic (I thought one solution would be to make each **joy_node** publish to a different topic namespace but couldn't find any solutions or tutorials for this).

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317932/how-to-distinguish-inputs-from-multiple-joysticks-on-joy-topic?/) by [Tashk](https://answers.ros.org/users/40373/tashk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The question being how do I distinguish/separate the two joysticks from each other in the joy topic

You can't. The [Joy](http://docs.ros.org/latest/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Joy.html) message has no field for that (theoretically `header.frame_id` *could* be used, but no consumer checks that).

> I thought one solution would be to make each `joy_node` publish to a different topic namespace

Yes, that would be one way to make sure they don't publish to the same topic.

> but couldn't find any solutions or tutorials for this

Well, "topic namespace[s]" don't exist. Perhaps that is why you couldn't find something.

You have two options:

1. use remapping (with [roslaunch](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap) or with [rosrun](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments)) to make each `joy_node` instance publish to a different topic
2. put both `joy_node`s in a different namespace (either directly on the [node](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node) or via a [group](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/group))

Which one would be more convenient depends on whether you already are using `.launch` files or not.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tashk](https://answers.ros.org/users/40373/tashk/) on 2019-03-09**:
Thank you, I found that creating a roslaunch file then remapping within it was exactly what i was looking for. Although took me a while to figure out the correct `<param>` definitions to separate the controllers in a launch file.

Here is my Roslaunch file code for anybody who struggles with the same issue

```
<launch>

<group>
    <remap from='joy' to='j0'/>
    <node pkg='joy' name='joy0' type='joy_node'>
        <param name='dev' type='string' value='/dev/input/js0'/>
    </node>
</group>

<group>
    <remap from='joy' to='j1'/>
    <node pkg='joy' name='joy1' type='joy_node'>
        <param name='dev' type='string' value='/dev/input/js1'/>
    </node>
</group>
```